# Mongoose validator on ObjectID not triggered

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a Pet schema defined as follows:

```js
export default {
  animal: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    validate: {
      validator(v) {
        if (
          (!this.animal && !this.crossbreed_animal) ||
          (this.animal && this.crossbreed_animal)
        )
          return false;
        return true;
      },
      message:
        "You must provide one of 'animal' or 'crossbreed_animal' ObjectId",
    },
  },
  crossbreed_animal: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: false },
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  birth_date: { type: Date, required: true },
  weight: { type: Number, required: false },
  ...
}
```

The issue is the validator not being triggered at all. (I ensured this by putting console.log() in various places in the validator)

However, it works flawlessly when the `type` field is not `Schema.Types.ObjectId`. I tried with the `weight` and `name` fields by copy/pasting the exact same validator code and it works as expected.

I google'd this issue but it seems like no-one has the same error.

What's the problem here?

Node version: v14.15.0,
Mongoose version: v.5.10.9

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to not put a validator that performs a validation of multiple fields on some fields like `animal`.

The best way to handle this is to define a `pre('save')` hook that will perform complex validation of the whole object. Though this does not actually answer why it does not work with `ObjectID` I would also advise you to submit an issue in the Mongoose repository if this is crucial for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I opted for implementing this `pre` hook as you suggested! Unfortunately, as this is not the answer for the question I specifically asked, I cannot mark you as accepted answer but still upvoted it!